# Passing Core Data Results Between View Controllers / Storyboard Scenes

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data, storyboard

Fairly new to Objective C and trying to work within Storyboards given it's the newest and greatest from Apple.

I'm curious, at a high level, what the preferred or best practice is for passing data between storyboard scenes where Core Data is the backend?  In other words, very simple example, one scene returns a set of data, then uses a seque to point to detail (i.e., passes some identifier from the set of data to the next scene which then displays additional information based on the passed data).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would pass the data as an object of some kind (either an array if that is what you are creating from the Core Data call, or a ManagedObject if you are only getting one "record" from Core Data).  If there isn't a good reason for making another FetchRequest, it is best to avoid doing so.

Passing this way means a Public Property on the receiving ViewController, and then you can set the value of that property in the prepareForSegue method.  If you need a complete example, I can add one later.